# SQL query to get products enabled, in stock without images?

Tags: magento2, database, sql

I'm running a Magento 2.3 and I would like to run a query in my database to export some products data that I don't have natively via the admin panel, the attributes are:

- Status
- Stock
- Images

How could I get it via SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this query bellow to have this data, I checked and set the **attribute_id manually**, so you will need to check it and change it to your `attribute_id`.

```
SELECT `e`.*,
       `at_status`.`value`         AS `status`,
       `at_price`.`value`          AS `price`,
       `at_image1`.value           as `image1`,
       `at_image2`.value           as `image2`,
       `at_small_image`.value      as `small image`,
       `at_swatch_image`.value     as `swatch_image`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status`
                    ON (`at_status`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND
                       (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `at_price`
                    ON (`at_price`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_price`.`attribute_id` = '77') AND
                       (`at_price`.`store_id` = 0)
         INNER JOIN `inventory_source_item` as `at_stock`
                    ON at_stock.sku = e.sku
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_image1`
                   ON (`at_image1`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_image1`.`attribute_id` = '48') AND
                      (`at_image1`.`store_id` = 0)
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_image2`
                   ON (`at_image2`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_image2`.`attribute_id` = '87') AND
                      (`at_image2`.`store_id` = 0)
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_small_image`
                   ON (`at_small_image`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_small_image`.`attribute_id` = '88') AND
                      (`at_small_image`.`store_id` = 0)
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_swatch_image`
                   ON (`at_swatch_image`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_swatch_image`.`attribute_id` = '175') AND
                      (`at_swatch_image`.`store_id` = 0)
WHERE (at_price.value >= 0)
  and at_status.value = '1'
  and at_stock.status = 1
  and (at_image1.value is null or at_image1.value IN ('', 'no selection'))
  and (at_image2.value is null or at_image2.value IN ('', 'no selection'))
  and (at_small_image.value is null or at_small_image.value IN ('', 'no selection'))
  and (at_swatch_image.value is null or at_swatch_image.value IN ('', 'no selection'))
```

Then you can save it in a SQL file and run it to generate a CSV.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u magentouser -pmagentopassword magentodbname < products-data.sql > products-data.csv
```